# "Scheduled to September" vs. "scheduled in September"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

> - She is qualified to attend the test being scheduled [to/in] September.

Which is right?

Comment: Related: [Schedule in the next week](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175049/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "scheduled for [time period]", but not "scheduled to [time period]".

The expressions "scheduled to take place in [time period]" or "scheduled to happen in [time period]" are acceptable, too.

"Scheduled in [time period]" is sometimes seen, but I'm inclined to read this as elliptic/short for "scheduled to take place in [time period]".