# Next week, in the next week, for the next week

Tags: prepositions, articles

I have an easy question about the usage of the expression: *next week / month/ year*.

What is the difference between these three sentences?

1. I'll probably go the mountains next week.
2. I'll be on holiday for the next week.
3. I'm sure there will be a lot of work to do in the next week.

I've found on the internet that the first sentence means "in a specific moment of the next week", but I can't understand the difference between the second and third sentence. What is the difference between *for the next* and *in the next*?

I've already tried looking for similar threads but none of them has answered my question. I hope you can help me!

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175049/schedule-in-the-next-week I've found this thread, but there is not the definite article (for the next...) in the answers. :(

Comment: Please understand that such terminology is rarely exceedingly precise.

Answer (score 6):

1) At some point during the next week, you will probably go to the mountains, but you do not intend to stay there for the entire week.

*"at a specific moment in the next week"*

2) You intend to go on holiday for the entire duration of the the next week.

*"for the entire duration of the next week"*

3) During the course of the next week, you expect a lot of work.

*"during the course of the next week"*

Comment: Thank you very much! What do you mean by "the next week" if today is Wednesday? Do you mean from next Sunday to Saturday or from today/tomorrow to next Wednesday?

Comment: It is somewhat context dependent.  For example, while speaking with a coworker at my workplace, "next week" is typically assumed to be the next work week, which is usually Monday to Friday, but may be different depending on the work.  However, without other context, the general assumption is as you describe, Sunday till Saturday.