# Scheduled FOR or IN the next days

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should be used in this sentence:

"She has 5 sessions scheduled for/in the next 7 days."

For context: I want to say that she has booked this number of sessions with the instructor and will take them during the next 7 days. Which preposition should I use in the sentence? I usually use "for" in such context, but also found examples with "in" that seem to have the same meaning...Or can I use both prepositions without no difference in the meaning?

Comment: To add more into the mix, I would say "Scheduled in" (verb/preposition) can be used for _creating_ a schedule — "The timetable for the June exams will be scheduled in the last week of May". People also use "scheduled-in" in place of just "scheduled" to mean the same thing — "I have your appointment scheduled-in for next Monday". See also [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175049/schedule-in-the-next-week). So would normally know by context which one you mean, but think "scheduled for" is clearer IMO that the sessions are taking place in the next 7 days

Comment: Related: [Schedule in the next week](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175049/).

Answer (score 1):

The relevant [usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scheduled%20*%20the%20next%20few&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cscheduled%20%2A%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscheduled%20for%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscheduled%20in%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscheduled%20within%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscheduled%20over%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cscheduled%20*%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscheduled%20for%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscheduled%20in%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscheduled%20within%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscheduled%20over%20the%20next%20few%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

(There will be valid alternatives such as [*scheduled **across***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22scheduled%20across%20the%20next%20few%22) or [***during** (some future time-span)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22scheduled%20during%20the%20next%20few%22) that simply don't occur often enough to show in a chart like that.)

---

I see no reason to suppose differences in intended *meaning*<sup>1</sup> might affect the choice of preposition. It's effectively a stylistic choice, but *learners* (non-native speakers) should probably stick to the most common *(**for**)*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Apart from [@anotherdave's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538857/scheduled-for-or-in-the-next-days/538862#comment1319680_538857) somewhat contrived difference when using ***to schedule*** as an "active" verb, whereby *The timetable for the June exams will be scheduled **in** the last week of May* would become nonsensical if we changed ***in*** to ***for***.

Comment: 'The relevant usage chart'? Do Google ngrams now factor in proportional representation for the spoken word?

Comment: Yo9u're seriously going to suggest that *for this particular usage*, we shouldn't assume that written forms reflect spoken forms? And even if ***isn't*** that accurate, who cares? Spoken or written, I'd bet my life that ***over*** is in fact more common that ***in***, which is the main reason the chart is "relevant" (it shows that OP is pointlessly agonizing over a choice between 2 options that don't even include the second most common preposition for the context).

Comment: I always use what I consider a necessary hedge: 'Google 5-grams suggest ...' / '... strongly suggest ... / ...'. Whereas 'The relevant usage chart ...' is peremptory.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I could go along with ***A** relevant chart...*, but in this particular case I think it's all a bit by the bye. The chart is only really here to show that ***several*** prepositions can be used in these contexts. And so far as I'm concerned, they're all interchangeable unless we extend the context to include "active" use of the verb ***to schedule***.

Answer (score 0):

"She has 5 sessions scheduled in the next 7 days." – **in = within**. She will have 5 sessions within the period of the next 7 days.

"She has 5 sessions scheduled for/in the next 7 days." – **for = in relation to**; (i) she will have 35 (5 x 7) sessions or (ii) "She has 5 sessions that are related to the next 7 days."

Comment: If this answer is intended to imply some ***semantic*** difference, I disagree.

Comment: Both versions are capable of meaning the same thing, but the second version has an additional meaning.

Comment: I cancelled my downvote, but I won't actually *upvote* unless you edit the answer text to explicitly point out that *versions are capable of meaning the same thing*. Imho they ***normally, by default*** mean the same, and your second example is unusual / contrived, not reflective of what native speakers would normally say or understand.